# How can I make git add -p accept keystrokes without waiting for me to press Enter?

Tags: git, interactive, git-add

`git add -p` is very convenient for staging changes in an interactive fashion. At each change, it prompts the user to press a key to determine what Git should do with the change in question:

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,j,J,g,s,e,?]?
```

Is there anyway to make git move onto the next hunk without having to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to make \`git add --patch\` respond to a single \`y\` or \`n\` keystroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546358/is-there-any-way-to-make-git-add-patch-respond-to-a-single-y-or-n-keystr)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Set the config option `interactive.singlekey` to `true`:

```
git config --global interactive.singlekey true
```

Comment: this is going to change my life

Comment: The [documentation says](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-interactivesingleKey) that Perl's Term::ReadKey is also needed.  Try `apt-get install libterm-readkey-perl`