# Is there any way to make `git add --patch` respond to a single `y` or `n` keystroke?

Tags: git

`git add --patch` is an integral part of my Git workflow. The only thing which irritates me about it is constantly having to press the Enter key after each `y` or `n`. Is there any way to make Git accept the answer to a question with just a single `y` or `n` keystroke?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That would be the Git configuration option `interactive.singleKey`.

> #### interactive.singleKey
>
> In interactive commands, allow the user to
>   provide one-letter input with a single    key (i.e., without hitting
>   enter). Currently this is used by the `--patch` mode of    `git-add(1)`,
>   `git-checkout(1)`, `git-commit(1)`, `git-reset(1)`, and `git-stash(1)`. Note
>   that this setting is silently ignored if portable keystroke input is
>   not available;    requires the Perl module `Term::ReadKey`.

That is, in your `.gitconfig` or equivalent file, add:

```
[interactive]
    singleKey = true
```

Or run `git config [--global] interactive.singleKey yes`, if you like `yes` better than `true` and commands better than editors.

Comment: I had to run `sudo cpan Term::ReadKey` to get the required Perl module.

Comment: On Ubuntu and related, you want the `libterm-readkey-perl` package

Comment: On Ubuntu Xenial, it's not quiet until applying @GeorgeHilliard's solution. It squawks: `missing Term::ReadKey, disabling interactive.singlekey`.

Answer (score 1):

> I had to run `sudo cpan Term::ReadKey` to get the required Perl module

Not with the next Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), since [`git-add--interactive.perl` is being ported in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275886/6309), and that involves `interactive.singlekey` .

See [commit b2627cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2627cc3d4be2f8086711097f99d79a32c6a703a), [commit 12acdf5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12acdf573aafb8633f710fdbe5ac1282165fc6cc), [commit e118f06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e118f06396bb298f2852070f648c6b4bb221a925), [commit 04f816b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04f816b125dc2649e70aad686d79b05bdc1d1c61), [commit a5e46e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5e46e6b0101b960c131dd39b50999cc0e69ed2b), [commit 9ea416c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ea416cb511e87f830462b08ae74b8a78fcca223), [commit 94ac3c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94ac3c31f730ab278e1373a942fb4503829f4279), [commit 08b1ea4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08b1ea4c39b08b76fe2d1240ccbf6077ef19226a), [commit 180f48d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/180f48df69d8e7a1a413d7c11907ecf975f09cf7), [commit 1e4ffc7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e4ffc765db69c1c2061452c122caf17c7fb25f3) (14 Jan 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 76c57fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76c57fedfa8a15bd341c0059bff164a049fe1d5c), 05 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`built-in add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12acdf573aafb8633f710fdbe5ac1282165fc6cc): handle Escape sequences more efficiently
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> When `interactive.singlekey = true`, we react immediately to keystrokes, even to Escape sequences (e.g. when pressing a cursor key).
>
> The problem with Escape sequences is that we do not really know when they are done, and as a heuristic we poll standard input for half a second to make sure that we got all of it.
>
> While waiting half a second is not asking for a whole lot, it can become quite annoying over time, therefore with this patch, we read the terminal capabilities (if available) and extract known Escape sequences from there, then stop polling immediately when we detected that the user pressed a key that generated such a known sequence.
>
> This recapitulates the remaining part of [b5cc003253c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5cc003253c8e1b505d5a2fbbcecb1ffcb409758) ("`add -i`: ignore terminal escape sequences", 2011-05-17, Git v1.7.6-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4961210b17725e3e3e975d84a5f7f718da5f218e)).
>
> Note: We do *not* query the terminal capabilities directly. That would either require a lot of platform-specific code, or it would require linking to a library such as `ncurses`.
>
> Linking to a library in the built-ins is something we try very hard to avoid (we even kicked the `libcurl` dependency to a non-built-in remote helper, just to shave off a tiny fraction of a second from Git's startup time). And the platform-specific code would be a maintenance nightmare.
>
> Even worse: in Git for Windows' case, we would need to query MSYS2 pseudo terminals, which `git.exe` simply cannot do (because it is intentionally *not* an MSYS2 program).
>
> To address this, we simply spawn `infocmp -L -1` and parse its output (which works even in Git for Windows, because that helper is included in the end-user facing installations).
>
> This is done only once, as in the Perl version, but it is done only when the first Escape sequence is encountered, not upon startup of `git add -i`; This saves on startup time, yet makes reacting to the first Escape sequence slightly more sluggish.
> But it allows us to keep the terminal-related code encapsulated in the [`compat/terminal.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12acdf573aafb8633f710fdbe5ac1282165fc6cc/compat/terminal.c) file.

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), the single-key interactive operation used by "[`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/214919b4f6a4ef69406d9383038f2a1a75476032/Documentation/git-add.txt#L96)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p))</sup> has been made more robust.

See [commit ac618c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac618c418e5e16acd82dc3d8e4356a39150de5a2), [commit 2c68602](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c6860211f211dfa5625dd1a5a69a802b4384dbb), [commit f7da756](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7da756566e8abf18abdf9e30a8ed6d2088770de), [commit 24d7ce3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24d7ce383a3d92feae6a641499448fde43206fd8) (22 Feb 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 214919b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/214919b4f6a4ef69406d9383038f2a1a75476032), 21 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac618c418e5e16acd82dc3d8e4356a39150de5a2): disable stdin buffering when `interactive.singlekey` is set
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> The builtin "`add -p`" reads the key "<kbd>F2</kbd>" as three separate keys "<kbd>^[</kbd>", "<kbd>O</kbd>" and "<kbd>Q</kbd>".
> The "<kbd>Q</kbd>" causes it to quit which is probably not what the user was expecting.
>
> This is because it uses `poll()` to check for pending input when reading escape sequences but reads the input with `getchar()` which is buffered by default and so hoovers up all the pending input leading `poll()` think there isn't anything pending.
>
> Fix this by calling `setbuf()` to disable input buffering if `interactive.singlekey` is set.

---

Since `git add` interactive is no longer in Perl, Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f9d4d28b7e6021b7e6db192b7bf47bd3a0d0d1d), removed the `singleKey` config part.

See [commit 64562d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64562d784de82f4ecd0c689ef8d6fa37f712707f) (18 Feb 2024) by [Julio Bacellari (`none`)](https://github.com/none).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ebd46ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebd46baf99d2ade14ebdf8fa62117434ce84609c), 27 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64562d784de82f4ecd0c689ef8d6fa37f712707f): remove outdated information about interactive.singleKey
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Julio Bacellari</sup>

> The Perl implementation of [`add --interactive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64562d784de82f4ecd0c689ef8d6fa37f712707f/Documentation/git-add.txt#L90)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---interactive))</sup> was removed in commit [1].
>
> Additionally, the `interactive.singleKey` setting is no longer silently ignored.
> The internal implementation of ReadKey [2] displays a warning if the platform is unsupported.
>
> - [1] [20b813d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20b813d7d3dc576aa58de22da2450b49116945bf) (`add`: remove , 2023-02-06, Git v2.40.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06bca9708ac86d286a6f5265ff0e6c532f44c657) listed in [batch #16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9d677b2d8cc5f70499db04e633ba7a400f64cbf)) (add: remove "add.interactive.useBuiltin" & Perl git add--interactive, 2023-02-06)
> - [2] [a5e46e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5e46e6b0101b960c131dd39b50999cc0e69ed2b) ("`terminal`: add a new function to read a single keystroke", 2020-01-14, Git v2.26.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76c57fedfa8a15bd341c0059bff164a049fe1d5c) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de93cc14ab7e8db7645d8dbe4fd2603f76d5851f))

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64562d784de82f4ecd0c689ef8d6fa37f712707f/Documentation/config/interactive.txt#L7):

> [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset), and [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).